# How to add a filter to products grid programmatically?

Tags: magento2

I've created an EAV attribute and I want to add a filter to products grid, like:

[image]

Could someone tell me what steps I have to do to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your new created attribute will be here under columns dropdown just click on checkbox and make it checked it will appear in filter .

[image]

Also make that settings in attribute for add that attribute in admin grid

[image]

programmatically you can create by below code create file **InstallData.php** in the location Vendor\Module\Setup

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        //product attribute
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            'product_attribute',
            [
                'type' => 'int',
                'label' => 'Prodct Atrribute',
                'input' => '',
                'class' => '',
                'source' => '',
                'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                'visible' => true,
                'user_defined' => false,
                'default' => '',
                'searchable' => true,
                'filterable' => true,
                'comparable' => false,
                'visible_on_front' => false,
                'used_in_product_listing' => true,
                'is_used_in_grid' => true,
                'is_filterable_in_grid'=> true,
                'unique' => false,
            ]
        );

    }

}
```

Comment: I want to do it programmatically

Comment: I have updated Answer please check

Comment: And what settings are mainly responsible for filtering here? I guess it's not only `filterable`.

Comment: 'is_used_in_grid' => true,

Comment: Well, a filter hasn't appeared in grid.

Comment: sorry i forget to add 'is_filterable_in_grid'= true, in code i have updated answer please check

Comment: also please make checked that attribute from admin columns drop down as i did in first screen shot

Comment: It appears now, thanks. Could you tell me why it does not filter a required information? I've created a dropdown eav attribute and created 2 products in which i set that attribute value to no and yes, tried to filter that but it doesn't filter nothing.

Comment: can you reindex first then check ?

Comment: I tried to create a new product and now that one created product filters normally.. Interesting. Thank you anyway!